# ¿Puedo tener certeza que esta Query usada en SQLite me devuelve 5 registros diferentes?

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Hola estoy usando esta query y me gustaria tener certeza que los 5  o registros que le indique seran diferentes o tendré que hacer una comparacion con los datos luego?

```
Sql = "SELECT * FROM t_compradores WHERE activo =1 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5;"
```

Comment: la unica certeza de esa consulta es que seran 5 elementos, y todos ellos tendran el campo `activo` a 1. Los registros deberian diferenciarse en el ID que uses en la tabla, pero eso no quita que haya campos repetidos. Eso ya depende de tu proceso y de la informacion que guardes en esa tabla.

Comment: si, van a ser 5 registros diferentes... ahora, que sea random... mmmm.... eso no lo veo real....

Comment: Funciona del modo que espero me devuelve 5 registros diferentes y hasta ahora las veces que provee nunca me trajo el mismo 2 veces en la misma iteraccion. Que quieres decir que random no?

Comment: Si, puedes tener certeza absoluta por que el select no duplica filas, el random solo aplica a como se ordenan esas filas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa la función DISTINCT en tu select:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM t_compradores WHERE activo =1 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5;
```

Igual siempre te recomiendo realizar una investigación por tu cuenta antes de recurrir a foros. Te dejo el enlace a la documentación [aquí](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-distinct/).